# AsciiDoc "referenced links" (as in Markdown)

Tags: markdown, asciidoc

[Reference-style links](https://en.support.wordpress.com/markdown-quick-reference/) are quite useful since I can refer to the links by its names. For instance, in Markdown I'm used to do something like:

```
The [Web site][tag-web-site] references...blah.

[tag-web-site]: https://web-site-url.tld
```

...and it will create a link based on the `tag-web-site` reference.

Is there any way I can mimic this functionality in AsciiDoc? I've tried but so far I can't find anything.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

AsciiDoc doesn’t have reference-style links, but you can use [attributes](http://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#setting-attributes-on-a-document) (variables) for the same purpose.

```
= Title
:tag-web-site: https://web-site-url.tld

The {tag-web-site}[Web site] references...blah.
```

Such attributes are usually prefixed with `uri-`, like `uri-web-site`.

Comment: ...awesome! Thanks!